# Android onSaveInstanceState and/or onRestoreInstanceState crashing

Tags: android

I am relatively new to programming for Android and I'm stuck on a (probably simple) issue. I've tried hours worth of messing around but getting nowhere...

My code is as follows, it stops the app when the device is rotated and the activity is restarted. I have used the  onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState methods but they aren't helping me! Could someone take a look please:

```
public class DebugActivity extends Activity implements GPSCallback{
private GPSManager gpsM=null;
private ConvertSpeed conS =null;
private double speed = 0.0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            speed = savedInstanceState.getDouble("speed");
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_debug);
        gpsM = new GPSManager();
        gpsM.startListening(getApplicationContext());
        gpsM.setGPSCallback(this);
        conS = new ConvertSpeed();
    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        outState.putDouble("speed",speed);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        speed = savedInstanceState.getDouble("speed");
    }
@Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        gpsM.stopListening();
        gpsM.setGPSCallback(null);
        gpsM = null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onGPSUpdate(Location location) {
        location.getLatitude();
        location.getLongitude();
        speed = location.getSpeed();
        String speedString = "" + conS.convertSpeed(speed,2);
        TextView debug1 = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSpeed));
        debug1.setText(speedString);
    }
}
```

Debugging:

In the `onCreate` method, the first time the Activity Runs:

```
if(savedInstanceState != null){
speed = savedInstanceState.getDouble("speed");
```

it shows `outState = null` and `speed = 0.0`

The screen rotates, the `onSaveInstanceState` method shows `outState = Bundle[{speed=0.0}]`, then 2 seconds later it crashes without reaching `onRestoreInstanceState` or `onCreate` again

Comment: *STACK TRACE*. We have no idea what your error is otherwise, and neither will you.

Comment: What have you seen when debugging or stepping through your code?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but I am researching how to use Stack Trace, I'm using IntelliJ. I'm also editing my question to show some debug information.

Comment: is this useful @kcoppock? "<1> main@830018184456" prio=5 runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:-1)
   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:3287)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:78)
   at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
   at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java:-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a more indepth look at the debugging log (after 3075 google searches apparantly...) and the error seemed to be was that I hadn't called `super.onDestroy()`! It appears to work now!!

Answer (score 0):

replace this `onCreate` to

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_debug);

        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            speed = savedInstanceState.getDouble("speed");
        }

        gpsM = new GPSManager();
        gpsM.startListening(getApplicationContext());
        gpsM.setGPSCallback(this);
        conS = new ConvertSpeed();
    }
```

and `onSaveInstanceState` to

```
 @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putDouble("speed",speed);
    }
```

Remove this `onRestoreInstanceState`

```
 @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        speed = savedInstanceState.getDouble("speed");
    }
```

after you did that its shall work fine

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Jack K Fouani but unfortunately this didn't work for me. I made the changes to the methods and removed the  onRestoreInstanceState method but the app still crashes in the same place.